# Возможно ли проигрывать онлайн-тв на html5?

Tags: html5, видео

Добрейшего всем времени суток! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно транслировать видео через html5? Есть несколько вариантов потока. Но, как я понял, их вообще невозможно завести в html5? Флешевые плееры находил, но не совсем вариант. Заранее спасибо за ответ. 
Потоки есть такие:

```
***/playlist.m3u8 
***/mpeg.2ts 
rtmp://*** 
rtsp://***
```

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1735933

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Технически 'Да'

**(Но в реальности - зависит от браузера...)**

HTML 5 тег `<video>` ничего не знает о протоколах.  Вы размещаете протокол в атрибут `src` как часть URL. Например:

```
<video src="rtp://myserver.com/path/to/stream">
   Ваш браузер не поддерживает VIDEO тег и/или потоки RTP.
</video>
```

Или:

```
<video src="http://myserver.com:1935/path/to/stream/myPlaylist.m3u8">
   Ваш браузер не поддерживает VIDEO тег и/или протокол данного видео.
</video>
```

Или даже что-то вроде:

```
<video>
  <source src="rtp://myserver.com/path/to/stream" type="video/rtp">
  <source src="http://myserver.com:1935/path/to/stream/myPlaylist.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">
  Ваш браузер не поддерживает VIDEO тег
</video>
```

Это говорит о том, что реализация тега `<video>` зависит от браузера. Если браузер поддерживает данный вид потоков - всё должно работать.

Из спецификации HTML5 от W3C:

> User agents may support any video and audio codecs and container formats
> Браузеры могут поддерживать любые видео, аудио кодеки и форматы контейнеров

[Перевод ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1737065/2110496)

---

Например, `Chromium` [заявляли](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=25573), что никогда не собираются поддерживать RTSP.