# Чем отобразить rtsp поток

Tags: rtsp

У меня есть ссылка вида

```
rtsp://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxx/user=admin&amp;password=admin&amp;channel=1&amp;stream=0.sdp?real_stream--rtp-caching=100
```

как мне вывести на сайт это видео? уже пересмотрел все, что нашел в гугле - не вышло

Comment: Вполне может быть, что никак, без перетрансляции собственным сервером: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/641966/181100

Comment: хорошо, а как сделать ретрансляцию? сервер есть, нашел статью на хабре - она не рабочая